# Adding two AppCompat Toolbars with different themes

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-toolbar

I would like to have two different android.support.v7.widget.Toolbars in my app, one dark, one light, and switch between them when needed. However, when I set a different theme on the second toolbar, it seems to reset the theme on the first toolbar as well.

Is that a bug or intended behavior?

Toolbar 1:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="top"
android:background="@drawable/action_bar_background"
sothree:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
sothree:contentInsetStart="0dp"/>
```

Toolbar 2:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/clip_toolbar"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="top"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
sothree:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
sothree:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
sothree:contentInsetStart="0dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a ContextThemeWrapper:

```
ContextThemeWrapper wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.Some_Theme);
```

Use the current Context to inflate one toolbar and use the ContextThemeWrapper to inflate the other. Use `getLayoutInflater()` to get the inflater for each context.

Comment: so this seems to work fine on Lollipop, but fails on Kitkat. Any ideas?

Comment: Can't tell you without a stack trace from logcat. Probably worth opening a new question

Comment: The bug is in the support library: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78289
And this solution doesn't work.