# How to use app:theme when extends Toolbar of Android support library

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library, android-toolbar

First, I want to change the color Menu Item color, I used this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/search_toolbar"
    style="@style/Widget.CustomActionBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/light_background"
    app:theme="@style/SearchToolbarTheme" />

<style name="SearchToolbarTheme" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/slate_grey</item> <!-- Arrow color -->
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/grey</item> <!-- Ripple effect color -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/dark_blue</item> <!-- Status bar color -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/dark_blue</item> <!-- Status bar color -->
    </style>
```

And it works well!

Then, I want to custom Toolbar:

```
public class SearchToolbar extends Toolbar {


public SearchToolbar(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public SearchToolbar(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}

private void init() {}
```

Change the xml file to

```
<com.abc.searchtoolbar.SearchToolbar xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/search_toolbar"
style="@style/Widget.CustomActionBar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@color/light_background"

app:theme="@style/SearchToolbarTheme" />
```

After that, the app:theme doesn't work anymore.

How can I keep the app:theme attribute in my custom view when I extends Toolbar?

Comment: can you provide your ActivityMain?

Comment: Reason why you extended and created a custom ToolBar? :/

Answer (score 0):

If you are extending a custom view from Toolbar you have to use that View in the xml file as well, so in your case:

```
<your.package.name.SearchToolbar xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/search_toolbar"
style="@style/Widget.CustomActionBar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@color/light_background"
app:theme="@style/SearchToolbarTheme" />
```

Comment: Sure, I did it on xml file.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the toolbar you want to achieve so that I can suggest the edits to your code

Answer (score 0):

For getting a custom Toolbar you don't need to create a new class and `extending` with `Toolbar`.you can use the following code in your Activity class.

```
// Always cast your custom Toolbar here
 Toolbar tb = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.yourCustomToolbarId);
 setSupportActionBar(tb);
```

Everything you want to change make it at xml file or style file.Then cast it your Activity class.

Comment: I know that. But that's only work around, and the code doesn't look good. the question is how can I re-use the app:theme attribute?

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around solution using **inflate**

```
public class SearchToolbar extends FrameLayout {


public SearchToolbar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public SearchToolbar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    inflate(getContext(), R.layout.layout_search_toolbar, this);}}
```

And inside layout_search_toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/search_toolbar"
style="@style/Widget.CustomActionBar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@color/light_background"
app:theme="@style/SearchToolbarTheme"
tools:showIn="@layout/layout_laz_appbar">
```

This solution is not bad, accept for we will have 1 more parent layout of Toolbar.

Comment: Hmm I was hoping to see the optimal solution of getting the theme attribute to work. Otherwise you are just wrapping the toolbar in a frame layout.

Comment: @user1325843 You should try ContextThemeWrapper, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26553772/adding-two-appcompat-toolbars-with-different-themes